# tar gzip mongo dump like MySQL

Tags: mongodb

Is there anyway to tar gzip mongo dumps like you can do with MySQL dumps?

For example, for mysqldumps, you can write a command as such:

```
mysqldump -u <username> --password=<password> --all-databases | gzip > all-databases.`date +%F`.gz
```

Is there an equivalent way to do the same for mongo dumps?

For mongo dumps I run this command:

```
mongodump --host localhost --out /backup
```

Is there a way to just pipe that to gzip? I tried, but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you run mongodump --help you will see an option to output to standard out, which is --out "-" . This should allow you to pipe into gzip as you do with mysql. I have not tested but worth a try.

Comment: Failing that you can do it as you do with MySQL, all that comamand does is pipe the mysqldump results into gzip, native linux functionality

Answer (score 102):

Version 3.2 introduced `gzip` and `archive` option:

`mongodump --db <yourdb> --gzip --archive=/path/to/archive`

Then you can restore with:

`mongorestore --gzip --archive=/path/to/archive`

Comment: Above restore, is restoring to the same database. How can I restore to a different database?

Comment: @SHIVA in mongodump, --db databaseName is the source and in mongorestore --db databaseName is the target database to restore into.

Comment: The archive format even allows you to skip naming an intermediate file and just work as a stream: `mongodump --archive | mongorestore --archive`. Very handy when you have to SSH to a server that has permission to do the dump.

Answer (score 16):

**Update (July 2015):**
[TOOLS-675](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-675) is now marked as complete, which will allow for dumping to an archive format in 3.2 and gzip will be one of the options in the 3.2 versions of the `mongodump/mongorestore` tools.  I will update with the relevant docs once they are live for 3.2

**Original answer (3.0 and below):**

You can do this with a single collection by outputting `mongodump` to `stdout`, then piping it to a compression program (gzip, bzip2) but you will only get data (no index information) and you cannot do it for a full database (multiple collections) for now.  The relevant feature request for this functionality is [SERVER-5190](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5190) for upvoting/watching purposes.

Here is a quick sample run through of what is possible, using `bzip2` in this example:

```
./mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: test
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad8a3eb74b5ae2ff0ec93a"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad8ba445be9c4f7bd018b4"), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad8ba645be9c4f7bd018b5"), "a" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad8ba845be9c4f7bd018b6"), "a" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53ad8baa45be9c4f7bd018b7"), "a" : 5 }
> 
bye
$ ./mongodump -d test -c foo -o - | bzip2 - > foo.bson.bz2
connected to: 127.0.0.1
$ bunzip2 foo.bson.bz2 
$ ./bsondump foo.bson
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8a3eb74b5ae2ff0ec93a" ), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8ba445be9c4f7bd018b4" ), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8ba645be9c4f7bd018b5" ), "a" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8ba845be9c4f7bd018b6" ), "a" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8baa45be9c4f7bd018b7" ), "a" : 5 }
5 objects found
```

Compare that with a straight `mongodump` (you get the same foo.bson but the extra foo.metadata.json describing the indexes is not included above):

```
$ ./mongodump -d test -c foo -o .
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2014-06-27T16:24:20.802+0100 DATABASE: test  to     ./test
2014-06-27T16:24:20.802+0100    test.foo to ./test/foo.bson
2014-06-27T16:24:20.802+0100         5 documents
2014-06-27T16:24:20.802+0100    Metadata for test.foo to ./test/foo.metadata.json
$ ./bsondump test/foo.bson 
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8a3eb74b5ae2ff0ec93a" ), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8ba445be9c4f7bd018b4" ), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8ba645be9c4f7bd018b5" ), "a" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8ba845be9c4f7bd018b6" ), "a" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53ad8baa45be9c4f7bd018b7" ), "a" : 5 }
5 objects found
```

Answer (score 8):

Export Mongodb as

```
mongodump --host <host-ip> --port 27017 --db <database>  --authenticationDatabase admin --username <username> --password <password> --gzip --archive >  dump_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz
```

Import as

```
mongodump --host <host-ip> --port 27017 --db <database>  --authenticationDatabase admin --username <username> --password <password> --gzip --archive=mongodump.gz
```

Comment: should be mongorestore?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it passing uri for your MongoDB replica set cluster

**Dump:**

```
mongodump --uri='mongodb://user:pass@primary_host,secondary_host/<db-name>?replicaSet=<replica-name>&authSource=admin' --gzip --archive > dump_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz
```

**Restore:**

```
mongorestore --uri='mongodb://user:pass@primary_host,secondary_host/<db-name>?replicaSet=<replica-name>&authSource=admin' --gzip --archive=<dump-file>.gz
```