# How to take db backup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, amazon-ec2

I am trying to backup my db by mongo in aws but i am getting an error and the command is as follows -

```
mongodump -u xxxx -p xxxx --db xxxx --authenticationDatabase=dbname --gzip --archive=Filepath
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To Dump:

```
mongodump -u username -p password -h x.x.x.x --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbname --gzip --out /data/
```

To Restore:

```
mongorestore -u username  -p password --host x.x.x.x --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbname --gzip  /data/
```

Comment: mongodump -u username -p password -h x.x.x.x --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbname --gzip --out /data/                                           space need to give between --out and /data

Answer (score 0):

To data dump

```
mongodump -u xxxx -p xxxx --db xxxx --authenticationDatabase=dbname --gzip --archive=/path/to/archive
```

It should work.

Reference link 
[tar gzip mongo dump like MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439068/tar-gzip-mongo-dump-like-mysql)
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/archiving-and-compression-in-mongodb-tools